# How to insert/update a data frame into Mongodb based on condition

Tags: mongodb, pandas, dataframe, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

Could someone please help in updating the Dataframe to Mongo based on below conditions.

If i have a similar date, i want to update the existing value. if i have the different date, i want to insert new document.

For example,

1) Consider i have the inserted the first data frame as below to Mongodb.

2) When i try to insert the second data frame, it should check if the date in the second DF is already exits in DB. If exists, it should update the existing names with there new ages and new count.

3) If i try to insert the data frame (third DF) where the data didn't exist in DB, it should insert the data frame.

First Data Frame:

```
data_1 = {'date':['2019-04-10','2019-04-10','2019-04-10','2019-04-10'],'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18],'Count':[5, 2, 1, 8]}
```

Second Data Frame:

```
data_2 = {'date':['2019-04-10','2019-04-10','2019-04-10','2019-04-10'],'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Age':[25, 21, 19, 16],'Count':[7, 3, 5, 8]}
```

Third Data Frame:

```
data_3 = {'date':['2019-04-11','2019-04-11','2019-04-11','2019-04-11'],'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Age':[25, 21, 19, 16],'Count':[7, 3, 5, 8]}
```

From the example above, db will finally have the second and third Data Frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue by delete the collection if the date exist. Thanks!!

```
import pandas as pd
import pymongo
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Age':[20, 33, 20, 18]})
now = datetime.datetime.now()
now = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
df.insert(0, 'Date', now)


#Making Mongo DB connections
conn = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
client = pymongo.MongoClient(conn)

#Creating DB
db = client.sample_db

#Creating collections for the DB
test_collection = db.test.find()

#Inserting into DB
db.test_collection.delete_many({"Date": now})
db.test_collection.insert_many(df.to_dict("records"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have understood. Try and let me know.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = client['test-database']
testData = db['test-data']
availableData = testData.find()

new_data = data_2
for obj in availableData:
    if obj['date'] == new_data['date']:
        testData.update(new_data)
        else:
            testData.insert(new_data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!! Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. I still have issue with update. May i know your mongodb version? I use MongoDB 4.0.6.
insert_many works for me but i still not sure on update/update_many.